# How to updates specific row in mysql(phpmyadmin) when dont know any colums value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to update column value of any(provided) row value.

**Table_A**

```
+--------+-----------+
|   num  | text      |
+--------+-----------+
|    1   | one       |
|    2   | two       |
|    3   | dont      |
|    4   | four      |
|    5   | five      |
+--------+-----------+
```

I want to update 3rd row value. Something like this:

```
update Table_A set `text`='three' Limit 2,1
update Table_A set `text`='three' where 1 Limit 2,1
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your *"3rd row"* has `num` column with value `3`, you may try this:

```
UPDATE `Table_A` SET `text` = 'three' WHERE `num` = 3;
```

Comment: as i said if i dont know any column value of rows. its just an example. now i am telling what i really want is.

Comment: @user3443146 couldn't you just put `ALTER Table_A ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;` to the table then `UPDATE ... WHERE id = X`? As others noted there is no reliable  way to identify table row by position because of number of reasons (`INDEX sorting` for example).

Answer (score 1):

"I want to update 3rd row value" -- there **is** no "third row". The order in which rows are returned should be regarded as **random** (even if it *usually* isn't) unless you specifically add an `ORDER` clause.

Even then, you cannot refer to a row by its position; the query that effects the `UPDATE` has no way of knowing which row you're referring to from the previous `SELECT`. You would need some function referring to the row being selected; some SQL dialects have `row_number()` function, similar to old Clipper `RECNO`. See also [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=181746).

What you can do is choose some identifying value and use that to refer to the row(s) you want:

```
UPDATE `Table_A` SET `text` = 'three' WHERE `num` IN ( 3 );
UPDATE `Table_A` SET `text` = 'three' WHERE `text` IN ( 'dont' );
```

More information on updating a table based on a ranking (which I guess is what you're looking for) can be found on the [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), see the notes about 'recno'.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

UPDATE `Table_A` SET `text` = 'three' WHERE `num` = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you expected like this

```
 UPDATE Table_A t1 join (SELECT num,(@Row := @Row + 1) AS row_number
    FROM Table_A, (SELECT @Row:=0) as row
) t2 ON t1.num=t2.num 
 SET t1.text='three' where t2.row_number='3'
```